# Next JS ( React ) doesn't understand stencil Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, stenciljs

With the current flow, React is hosting stencil JS components in our SPA, as usual its now impacting on SEO and performance as the increase in scope and the point were we can't alter major architecture decisions.

But from the proof of concept point of view, started to evaluate Next JS with Stencil js. The challenges coming are

- Hydration mismatch
- The React is not able to understand stencil prop. The same works in our traditional app.

[image]

The Solution tried are-

- used React Wrapper component but it doesn't help either.

Is it like Next JS is unable to ignore custom elements ?

Please throw some light on this.

Comment: With reference to https://stenciljs.com/docs/react 

It seems I have to only try with React wrapper components.

As per documentation - 
"Properties and attributes that are not a string or number will be correctly bound to the component"

Answer (score 0):

Yes based on the stencil documentation, we need wrapper React component for stencil to understand.

Added a reference link in my earlier comment. Hence closing this.